# Python: "import JSON... json.loads(request.body)" 2.7->3.4

Tags: python, json, django, python-2.7, python-3.x

I recently converted a django server to python version 3.4.1 from python version 2.7.
My request.body is an array serialized to JSON. When de-serialized it will be a python list.

Unfortunately, it would seem that json.loads no longer takes raw bytes (which is what request.body is).

How can I fix this issue?

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':

        print("Made it here!")
        registered = []
        notRegistered = []
        print("Is it this?")

        print(repr(request.body))

        data = json.loads(request.body)

        print("Did I make it here?")
```

The last call to print never executes, which is why I'm assuming it has to do with json.loads()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect a traceback to occur rather than just "the last line never executing", but that aside...

```py
# Let's just assume the request is UTF-8 encoded.
data = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: In my case I have request.body = str: json=%7B%22layers%22%3A%7B%22BackgroundLayer%22%3**, and json.loads gives me the error ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded, why?